# DNS names on virtual machines don't work

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a problem with my virtual machines:

I have three machines. VM5 has connected to internet network via NAT. It can ping both 8.8.8.8 and google.com. VM1 and VM2 ping 8.8.8.8 but can't ping google.com.

Is it some problem with DNS?

The VM5 has POSTROUTING MASQUERADE.

UPD:

[image: VM1 to gooogle.com ping]

[image: tcpdump on VM5]

[image: /etc/resolv.conf on VM5]

[image: Network scheme]

[image: VM5 configuration]

UPD 2:

I have 2 networks:

- 192.168.1.0/24 is red ellipse on the picture.
- 192.168.2.0/24 is green ellipse.
  VM5 has NAT to get access to Internet Network.

I use debian OS on all machines.

UPD3:

VM5:

[image: ping 192.168.0.1]

[image: nslookup google.com]

Comment: Do you have a forwarding DNS resolver on port 53 of VM5? Your drawing is unclear. Could you [edit] your Question and describe your network in text? What OSs are you running everywhere?

Comment: @waltinator I added additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If a given VM can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com, I guess it isn't well configurated about DNS. A `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in the `/etc/resolv.conf` could resolve the issue.

Comment: I've added `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to the question

Comment: Ok, the DNS is set to 192.168.0.1, but is there a DNS there ? Is 192.168.0.1 reachable (ping) ? Try `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` and `nslookup google.com 192.168.0.1` and compare…

Comment: I don't know what is computer on 192.168.0.1. I added sreenshots to the question.

Comment: If you have a whole configuration with no 192.168.0.1 host, it can’t function with the nameserver you have. Note that 192.168.0.1 is a common ISP gateway. The nameserver may have been set by a DHCP.